# Is there a way to measure distance to a surface of a liquid (water for example) using the V6180 time of flight sensor?

Tags: sensor, measurement, laser

I'm using the [Vl6180](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vl6180.pdf) time of flight sensor to measure a distance to a surface.

This surface is a liquid, water for example. In my setup, the sensor doesn't detect the surface, the pulses from the laser goes right through. It seems there is not enough reflection at the surface.

Putting something on the surface that will reflect is not a solution in my case.

Comment: Are you wedded to using this particular sensor given the issues with detection? An ultrasonic sensor could be a cheap alternative see https://www.circuitstoday.com/water-level-indicator-arduino-ultrasonic-sensor#:~:text=Arduino%20Water%20Level%20Indicator%20Circuit&text=Fig1%2C%20in%20this%20circuit%20an,is%20transmitted%20by%20RF%20transmitter. for an example idea

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot put a dye in the liquid the only alternative I can think of is to make sure the beam from the chip hits the surface of the liquid at an [angle](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-3/The-Critical-Angle) that will guarantee some reflection. In order to recover the reflected beam you would also need to factor in a mirror to return the reflected beam to the chip.

Comment: Maybe the dye could work, only the dye should be compatible with an IR laser.

Comment: @paulusvanderEnd Almost any dye would be suitable since it is very near IR. You could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodamine_B

Answer (score 0):

Generally, TOF laser distance sensors are not suitable for measuring distances to anything that is transparent at the laser's wavelength.

Bouncing the laser beam at an angle may work, but the problem then would be getting the bounced laser light back to the sensor, and doing the math to get the actual distance.

Strangely, [success has been reported with a specific sensor](https://www.hackster.io/team-protocentral/liquid-level-sensing-using-a-laser-tof-sensor-d04232), but I don't know how reproducible it will prove to be; I haven't tried.